# html encoded character instead of normal username in comment

Tags: bug, mobile-app

I made a comment with a user that had a `ì` in the username on the mobile app on stack overflow to tag him.

Unfortunately, this isn't rendered properly and replaced by a html entity, which is then probaly replaced by another html entity run.

[image: Image that shows html entity code]

Aparently it also doesn't show up right in the network wide activity. Found by [rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene)

[[image: Network wide image that shows the problem][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0nRy.png)

Comment: It might not be relevant to the problem, but the App and Web examples have "Christian" and "Cristian", respectively.

Comment: @RayButterworth Yea, that would be a typo on my side, no real auto complete in the app for usernames, and when typing you have like a 2 line high window where you can see the original post. Still the ì should have have rendered properly I think. This post ins't really about tagging, it's about the double encoded htmlentity.